# pagination ruins other actions webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, pagination

I'm trying to implement pagination for a resource in webapi, but it ruined other action which return singleById resource.

So there are two functions for getting object/s in my api ( one single another mass but paged ) like below:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int page,string type="mm");
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id);
```

The type option is a semi search like optional filter.

I know it has conflicts i made it string id but it didn't work, i thought about a way routing each action separately or renaming them but it doesn't work cause the default route is like `api/{controller}/{id}` and doesn't include action names beside i don't like to have `api/{controller}/post/` to be generated.

Comment: Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[Route("specefiedController/{id}/single")]
```

to have `getById` action and let the other actions be as they were